# Script to disable build steps in TeamCity or start run at a specific step

Tags: rest, api, powershell, teamcity-8.0

I want to disable several build steps in a TeamCity configuration.
For example:

> - I have a deploy configuration called *DeploySoftware*.
> - It has 10 build steps (Run >*DB scripts*, *Run environment scripts*, *Deploy Web Service*, *Deploy Windows Service*, *Deploy This*, *Deploy That*, etc).
> - I run it once and it fails on *Deploy This*.
> - I want to run it again starting with *Deploy This*, **OR** disable all the previous steps to that one by using a script.

One config I have has 30 build steps, so if it fails at Step 28 (and I know that another run will most likely work) I want to run it again starting with Step 28.  Otherwise it's 45 minutes of running steps that have already successfully complete, before I get to the step that needs to be run.

I don't need the script to run the build (although that'd be nice), or change the config back once it's run (I expect that would be a simple tweak to the disable script).

The script could be PowerShell, C#, VB.NET, VBA, Ruby - pretty much anything that I can quickly amend and run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following script will disable or enable the build steps from 1 => x

```
# -----------------------------------------------
# Build Step Disabler
# -----------------------------------------------
#
# Ver   Who                  When      What
# 1.0   Evolve Software Ltd  29-03-16  Initial Version

# Script Input Parameters
param (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $RestEndPoint = $(throw "-RestEndPoint is mandatory, please provide a value."),
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $ApiUsername = $(throw "-ApiUsername is mandatory, please provide a value."),
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $ApiPassword = $(throw "-ApiPassword is mandatory, please provide a value."),
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [int] $FailedStep = $(throw "-FailedStep is mandatory, please provide a value."),
    [bool] $Disable = $True
)

function Main() 
{
    $CurrentScriptVersion = "1.0"
    $ApiCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ApiUsername, (ConvertTo-SecureString $ApiPassword -AsPlainText -Force))

    $ApiCredentials_ForHeader = $ApiUsername + ":" + $ApiPassword
    $ApiCredentialsBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ApiCredentials_ForHeader))

    $ApiCredentialsHeader = @{};
    $ApiCredentialsHeader.Add("Authorization", "Basic $ApiCredentialsBase64")

    Write-Host "================== Build Step Disabler - Version"$CurrentScriptVersion": START =================="

    # Log input variables passed in
    Log-Variables
    Write-Host

    # Get the steps into XML
    [System.Xml.XmlDocument]$stepsResponse = Api-Get "$RestEndPoint/steps"
    $currentStep = 1;

    do {
        try {
            [System.Xml.XmlElement]$step = $stepsResponse.steps.step[$currentStep-1]

            if (!$step.id)
            {
                Write-Output "Build step id not found - Exiting"
                Exit 1
            }

            $stepId = $step.id
            Api-Put "$RestEndPoint/steps/$stepId/disabled" ($Disable).ToString().ToLower()
            $currentStep++
        } 
        catch [System.Exception] {
            Write-Output $_
            Write-Output "Unable to configure the build steps correctly"
            Exit 1
        }
    } 
    while ($currentStep -le $FailedStep)

    Write-Host "================== Build Step Disabler - Version"$CurrentScriptVersion": END =================="
}

function Log-Variables
{
    Write-Host "RestEndPoint: " $RestEndPoint
    Write-Host "FailedStep: " $FailedStep
    Write-Host "Disable: " $Disable
    Write-Host "Computername:" (gc env:computername)
}

function Api-Get($Url)
{
    Write-Host $Url
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $ApiCredentialsHeader -Credential $ApiCredentials -Uri $Url -Method Get -ContentType "application/xml" -TimeoutSec 30;
}

function Api-Put($Url, $Data)
{
    Write-Host $Url
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $ApiCredentialsHeader -Credential $ApiCredentials -Uri $Url -Method Put -ContentType "text/plain" -Body $Data -TimeoutSec 30 -DisableKeepAlive;
}    

Main
```

**Usage**:

This will disable the build steps 1 => 5

```
script.ps1 "http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/DeploySoftware" username password 5
```

This will enable the build steps 1 => 5

```
script.ps1 "http://teamcity/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/DeploySoftware" username password 5 $false
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, that's great. I had to increase the timeouts (very slow/busy server), but this worked perfectly.

Comment: That is a beautifully written script.